# How to ajaxify a shopping cart in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having problems [Ajaxifying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) a shopping cart built in [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter). When a user clicks on an add button on a drop down menu for items, the item becomes added onto a div called #cart via an Ajax callback function. However, my issue is that the content generated via Ajax in the cart div is not permanent (since this is done on the client side).  Is there a way to make the cart [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) output permanent while still using Ajax?

Although my Ajax call is outputing the content from my controller, i checked out the view source and there is actually no html elements on it.Here is my ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add').click(function(){
        var button =$(this).val();
        var button = button.split(',');
        var url=<?php echo '"' . base_url() . 'index.php/order_form/add/"' ?>+button[0]+'/'+button[1];
        var quantity=$('#quantity-'+button[0]).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data:'quantity='+quantity,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(output_string){
                $('#cart').empty().append(output_string);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: have you tried storing to cookies or sessions ? so CI can `remember` what items are selected..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

- Store the response from Ajax in a CodeIgniter session. This means you will be
  able to verify the session at a refresh and repopulate the cart.
- Store the response from Ajax in a temporary database table... and again,
  at a refresh, repopulate the cart from the database.

General facts: you will never be able to see Ajax's response by looking at the source code. You will have to look with a browser inspector at the response ([XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) response at the network tab in [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), for example). There you will see what URL was outputed for you through Ajax.

Comment: I'm storing values in CL's shopping cart class (using the custom session class database).  My issue is I want it to update when the users change the quantity value in the cart without having to refresh the page.